# pip install can't import pkg_resources

Tags: python, pip

I tried to install a package with `pip`.  I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I tried reinstalling pip and setuptools but this didn't seem to fix it.  How do I fix this problem so I can install packages with pip?

Comment: Why exactly was that downed ?

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my question? ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I manually deleted everything associated with pip.

1. Change dir to /local/bin, `rm -fr pip*`
2. Change dir to /opt/local/bin, `rm -fr`
3. Used brew to uninstall python entirely.
4. Used brew to reinstall python.

Python 2.7.9 comes with pip and it is now functioning.